# Laravel 4 Generate HTTPS URL's

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is it at all possible for Laravel 4 to generate proper HTTPS URL's with **every** item? Or at least generate relative URL's instead of absolute (which I cannot fathom why this is not the default behavior).

Every form generated via Laravel Eg:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'login', 'method' => 'post')) }} //http://example.com/login
```

Will always use http as the protocol. In Laravel 3 there was open_secure method, but that is no longer inside Laravel 4.

Every Route generated by Laravel Eg:

```
{{ URL::route('login') }} //http://example.com/login
```

etc, etc

**NOTE**: You can get around Route's by using:

```
{{ URL::route('login', array(), false) }} // /login - This is perfect behavior
```

This create a relative URL which is safe over every protocol.

**Note 2**: Creating a filter is **not** an acceptable solution. It creates issue with POST forms and creates a redirect on every single page. Why increase load and wait times?

Comment: Is the page you are starting on also have https? i.e. the page where the link is shown - is that https?

Comment: This is a real PITA problem I'm facing now too...

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://github.com/laravel/docs/blob/4.1/routing.md#forcing-a-route-to-be-served-over-https):

```
Route::get('login', array('https', function()
{
    return 'Must be over HTTPS';
}));
```

If the route is not defined to be http-only or https-only, the scheme of the current request is used ([source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.1/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L398-L418)).

Comment: Hmm interesting, but that does not appear to be the case, behind a load balanced server (which Laravel has trouble detecting HTTPS/HTTP) or a regular single instance server

Comment: I'm quite sure that Laravel 4 needs improvement on this, but if you define the route to be https-only, it should work in any case.

Comment: I know it is closed and old but if I have

Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
How would I make it have the https attr?

Comment: @RaduM I suggest you to post a brand new SO question for that

Answer (score 0):

If the communication between your load balancer and the website is HTTPS as well then matpop's solution will work.

If the load balancer handles the HTTPS part of the request I would suggest to add a header and check if that header exists and is the expected value. How to configure this (probably it's already configured by default) would depend on your load balancer.